# Final variable of `enum` type does not produce error when perform an assignment

Tags: java, enums, variable-assignment, final

So I was cleaning my code and adding `final` keywords to whichever places possible, one of those place happen to be an uninitialized variable of `enum` type.

The variable is not initialized because its value needs to be determined by a `switch` statement. It would not make sense to make this variable `final` in this case but I did it anyways by accident, and found out that the code works fine without producing any error.

With my understanding, an uninitialized variable in Java will hold a default value (which in this case I think should be `null`), and a final variable cannot be re-assigned to a different object.

---

**How come this code does not produce any error nor side effect?**

**Notes:**

- `NeighborPosition` is an enum type

```java
final NeighborPosition edgePosition;
switch(cornerPosition) {
    case ONE:
        edgePosition = NeighborPosition.THREE;
        break;
    case TWO:
        edgePosition = NeighborPosition.FOUR;
        break;
    case THREE:
        edgePosition = NeighborPosition.FIVE;
        break;
    case FOUR:
        edgePosition = NeighborPosition.SIX;
        break;
    case FIVE:
        edgePosition = NeighborPosition.ONE;
        break;
    case SIX:
        edgePosition = NeighborPosition.TWO;
        break;

    case ZERO:
    default: {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Should never reach this corner, current corner: "
            + cornerPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: "uninitialized variable in Java will hold default value" <- That is only true for class fields. Local variables do not have default values.

Comment: There is no error because your switch will, for each possible flow, either assign a value or throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you @OHGODSPIDERS for explaining that, I think this was the biggest reason to my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variable are not initialized by default, only fields are.

In all possible cases, your code will either assign a value to `edgePosition` or throw an exception (in which case, the local variable gets  out of scope).